# Headless browser in Azure functions JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I tried using phantomjs but apparently it's unsupported, is there any way to scrape websites using azure functions in javascript?

Comment: why not use node.js? Any language available in webjobs is available in functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many restrictions on Azure App Service (includes WebApps, Function Apps), such as [Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions). So some packages are not supported on Azure App Service, which like PhantomJS/puppteer be required to start a headless browser which needs GDI support to communicate with javascript/nodejs to get DOM node.

You can scrape a static web page or only HTML via Node [`http.ClientRequest`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) or [Request](https://github.com/request/request) package in Function App. If to scrape a DOM node of a web page dynamically, the only way is using PhantomJS/puppteer on Azure VM, not Function Apps.