# How to deploy asp.net core app to work with headless browser without VM machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, selenium-chromedriver, azure-web-app-service

I have an application in asp.net core where I use selenium chromewebdriver. This app is used for web scraping which wors on my localhost IIS Express. My problem is that I want to deploy this app on Azure with possible to run headless chrome browser. I managed to to this but I had an error:

*"unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary"*

So I extracted the chromium but that didn't help, another error:

*"unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process.
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)"*

I heard about Azure WebJobs but it has limitation to 50MB.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958882/run-selenium-chrome-webdriver-on-azure-cloud-service?rq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708299/headless-browser-in-azure-functions-javascript

But this questions doesn't have code samples but people answered them so?

Comment: @janek9971 that post you linked also explains how to fix your problem btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Selenium Chrome WebDriver on Azure Cloud Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958882/run-selenium-chrome-webdriver-on-azure-cloud-service)

Comment: @Timothy Groote
I read that before asking, but couldn't understand Sangeet how to achieve it what he wrote. 
First answer referfs to PhantomJSDriver which I don't use.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, impossible to do. Your question is similar with the other SO threads I had answered as below.

1. [Headless browser in Azure functions JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708299/headless-browser-in-azure-functions-javascript/53719786#53719786)
2. [Can I use phantomJS on Azure app service for linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54013360/can-i-use-phantomjs-on-azure-app-service-for-linux/54035137#54035137)

There is a new article [`Headless Selenium Browsers`](https://www.infoq.com/articles/headless-selenium-browsers) comes from InfoQ, it compares 5 options of headless browser which include `Chrome Driver` requires `Chrome` installed first. However, there is a limits about [`Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) of Azure Web App sandbox. So any library requires GDI support can not run on Azure WebApp, which even includes [JBrowser](https://jbrowse.org/) requires [`libpng` & `libgd2`](https://github.com/GMOD/jbrowse/wiki/JBrowse_Configuration_Guide#making-a-new-jbrowse).

Therefore, using VM to run headless browser is the only one solution on Azure.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I changed approach and I use the website API to send request and scrape data without headless browser.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) for scraping?

Comment: This is dynamic website , I have to perform scrolling to load all.